# Animate Textview inside a listview row

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple problem:
i have a listview with 2 TextViews one shows a number and the other shows the diff from last time the number has chnaged.

What im trying to do is every time the getView is called on my adapter show an animation on the second TextView based on the change in the first Textview number. im trying to do this for all of the items inside the listview and it doesnt work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,
   Totem

Comment: Never done this before but have you tried using TextSwitcher?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way you can achieve this is by extending SimpleCursorAdaptor or ArrayAdaptor [(How to...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988386/listactivity-with-custom-layout-does-not-call-getview)

in the bindView method you based on the logical check you can then show the animated version of the TextView and hide the none animated.

This is the easiest way I have implemented.

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/