# ListActivity with custom layout does not call getview

Tags: android, listactivity, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListActivity with a custom row layout.  The row layout consists of a checkbox, a textview and an imagebutton.

Behind this is an ArrayList of a custom object containing simply a String and a boolean.  I want to checkbox to reflect the boolean, the textview to reflect the Sting, and the button on the right will kick off an action.

I use the last constructor listed on the ArrayAdapter page to try to bind this all together.  `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)`

For some reason the textView is populated by the objects toString(), and not by getView.  Therefore the checkbox never gets the boolean value at all.  Any ideas?

```
public class ListSelection extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<ListItem> list;
    private ArrayList<String> deleted;  

    static private final String TAG = "kinder";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "ListSelection.onCreate");   

        list = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        deleted = new ArrayList<String>();

        Intent temp = getIntent();
        String[] listNames = temp.getStringArrayExtra("listNames");
        boolean[] listStatus = temp.getBooleanArrayExtra("listStatus");
        for (int i = 0; i < listNames.length; i++) {
            list.add(new ListItem(listNames[i], listStatus[i]));
        }

        **setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ListItem>(this, R.layout.selectionlistitem, R.id.text, list));**

    }

    private class ListItem {
        String listName;
        Boolean listStatus;     
        public ListItem(String name, boolean status) {
            listName = name;
            listStatus = status;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return listName;
        }
    }

    public class ListItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {
        int resource;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        private List<ListItem> items;

        public ListItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int _resource, List<ListItem> listitems) {
            super(context, _resource, listitems);
            Log.d(TAG, "listItemArrayAdapter");
            vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            resource = _resource;
            this.items = listitems;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "listItemArrayAdapter.getView");
            LinearLayout newView;

            ListItem item = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                newView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
                vi.inflate(resource, newView);
            } else {
                newView = (LinearLayout)convertView;
            }

            TextView textview = (TextView)newView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            Log.d(TAG, item.listName);
            textview.setText(item.listName);

            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)newView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            checkbox.setChecked(item.listStatus);
            return newView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you should replace this line:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ListItem>(this, R.layout.selectionlistitem, R.id.text, list));
```

with this:

```
setListAdapter(new ListItemArrayAdapter<ListItem>(this, R.layout.selectionlistitem, list));
```

As it stands, you are using the default view generation logic of `ArrayAdapter`, which is to feed `toString()` for each array element to a `TextView`.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  You won't believe how much time I spent on this without seeing that mistake.  Thanks a ton!